# How to change a particular element of a C++ STL vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

```
vector<int> l;
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
   l.push_back(i);
}
```

Now, for example, **how do I change the `5th element` of the vector to `-1`?**

I tried `l.assign(4, -1);`
It is not behaving as expected. None of the other vector methods seem to fit.

*I have used vector as I need random access functionality in my code (using `l.at(i)`).*

Comment: Anything wrong with l[4] = -1; Or l.at(4) = -1, if you prefer.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

`at` and `operator[]` both return a reference to the indexed element, so you can simply use:

```
l.at(4) = -1;
```

or

```
l[4] = -1;
```

Comment: And you'd better take the habit to use `at`, less idiomatic, but bound-checking is priceless.

Comment: @Matt: Though out of bounds errors tend to be a programmer fault, while `at` throws an exception. That is to say, an `assert` would be better, and I think both MSVC and gcc have checked iterators.

Comment: @GMan Personally, I've more or less stopped using asserts. I tend to use at() in situations where I might make a coding mistake (I wouldn't use one in a for-loop, for example) - something I'm just as likely to do when writing an assert.

Comment: We don't use `assert` where I work. We have a test environment that is supposed to be stable, so that clients can test on it without being interrupted too often, and therefore we have a simili assert which throws instead of aborting the program... therefore `at` and `ASSERT` have the very same effect for me :)

Comment: @MatthieuM., sorry in advance if my question is too basic but what did you mean by **bound-checking** and **bound-checking is priceless**? If possible, could you please elaborate on that? Thank you!

Comment: @Milan: Actually, this should read _bounds_-checking, which is the act of checking the bounds. If you have a vector `vec` which contains 5 elements, attempting to access the element at index 5 is an error, the valid indices are 0 through 4 (included), and 5 and upwards point to no element. `vec[5]` will... do something. Likely reinterpreting whatever bytes are left there as if they were a valid object, or maybe worse. It's Undefined Behavior so anything could happen, really. `vec.at(5)` however will _first_ check the bounds before accessing the element, and throw in this case.

Comment: @MatthieuM. got your point now. So, I created a vector: `std::vector<int> vec = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};` and I ran `std::cout << vec[5];` multiple times in my **gcc** and every time, it displayed `0`. On the other hand, when I tried running `std::cout << vec.at(5);`, I got `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 5) >= this->size() (which is 5)
Aborted (core dumped)` error. I didn't know about this behavior before. So, thank you so much for pointing out this :)

Answer (score 25):

Even though @JamesMcNellis answer is a valid one I would like to explain something about error handling and also the fact that there is another way of doing what you want.

You have four ways of accessing a specific item in a vector:

- Using the `[]` operator
- Using the member function `at(...)`
- Using an iterator in combination with a given offset
- Using `std::for_each` from the `algorithm` header of the standard C++ library. This is another way which I can recommend (it uses internally an iterator). You can read more about it for example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/).

In the following examples I will be using the following vector as a lab rat and explaining the first three methods:

```
static const int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int> v(arr, arr+sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
```

This creates a vector as seen below:

```
1 2 3 4
```

First let's look at the `[]` way of doing things. It works in pretty much the same way as you expect when working with a normal array. You give an index and **possibly** you access the item you want. I say **possibly** because the `[]` operator doesn't check whether the vector actually has that many items. This leads to a silent invalid memory access. Example:

```
v[10] = 9;
```

This may or may not lead to an instant crash. Worst case is of course is if it doesn't and you actually get what seems to be a valid value. Similar to arrays this may lead to wasted time in trying to find the reason why for example 1000 lines of code later you get a value of `100` instead of `234`, which is somewhat connected to that very location where you retrieve an item from you vector.

A much better way is to use `at(...)`. This will automatically check for `out of bounds` behaviour and break throwing an `std::out_of_range`. So in the case when we have

```
v.at(10) = 9;
```

We will get:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>   what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 10) >= this->size()
>   (which is 4)

The third way is similar to the `[]` operator in the sense you can screw things up. A vector just like an array is a sequence of continuous memory blocks containing data of the same type. This means that you can use your starting address by assigning it to an iterator and then just add an offset to this iterator. The offset simply stands for how many items after the first item you want to traverse:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); // First element of your vector
*(it+0) = 9;  // offest = 0 basically means accessing v.begin()
// Now we have 9 2 3 4 instead of 1 2 3 4
*(it+1) = -1; // offset = 1 means first item of v plus an additional one
// Now we have 9 -1 3 4 instead of 9 2 3 4
// ...
```

As you can see we can also do

```
*(it+10) = 9;
```

which is again an invalid memory access. This is basically the same as using `at(0 + offset)` but without the out of bounds error checking.

I would advice using `at(...)` whenever possible not only because it's more readable compared to the iterator access but because of the error checking for invalid index that I have mentioned above for both the iterator with offset combination and the `[]` operator.

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
l[4] = -1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [subscript operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/operator[]/)

```
l[4] = -1
```

Comment: Hi Tom,Can you tell how to acheive this for 2D vectors,like "vector<vector<int>> VC" or "vector<int> VC (100,100)".

Answer (score 3):

I prefer

```c
l.at(4)= -1;
```

while [4] is your index